# Authentication on odata service

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, wcf-data-services, odata

I want to add some authentication to my odata service.  Depending on the user calling i want to: filter rows and/or remove columns.

I read in scott hanselmans fine blogpost on odata ( http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx )that it is possible to intercept the incoming queries. If this works i could add some extra filtering.

How would this intercepting and altering queries work exactly? I can not find any examples of where and how to do this.

(i'm using entitie framework and wcf dataservices (just like scotts example blog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use query interceptors for this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/15/pre-filtering-and-shaping-odata-feeds-using-wcf-data-services-and-the-entity-framework-part-1.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/15/pre-filtering-and-shaping-odata-feeds-using-wcf-data-services-and-the-entity-framework-part-2.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744837.aspx

Comment: Great! Can one remove columns as well?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to dynamically remove columns.